Getting Error CORS Policy: Angular and Spring Boot
I am getting the following error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/basicauth' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

How do I resolve this issue?
Here is the Github link to my project.
For configuration, I did this:
package com.sofi.rest.webservices.restfulwebservices.basic.auth;


public class AuthenticationBean {

    private String message;

    public AuthenticationBean(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("HelloWorldBean [message=%s]", message);
    }

  }




package com.sofi.rest.webservices.restfulwebservices.basic.auth;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

//Controller
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
public class BasicAuthenticationController {

    @GetMapping(path = "/basicauth")
    public AuthenticationBean helloWorldBean() {
        //throw new RuntimeException("Some Error has Happened! Contact Support at ***-***");
        return new AuthenticationBean("You are authenticated");
    }   
}


package com.sofi.rest.webservices.restfulwebservices.basic.auth;
import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfigurationBasicAuth {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll());

        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());

        http.httpBasic(withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

}

package com.sofi.rest.webservices.restfulwebservices.basic.auth.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .allowedMethods(HttpMethod.GET.name(),
                        HttpMethod.POST.name(),
                        HttpMethod.PUT.name(),
                        HttpMethod.DELETE.name())
                .allowedHeaders(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,
                        HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
    }

My POM.XML file:
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>com.sofi.rest.webservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>restful-web-services</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>restful-web-services</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         
         
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

http-intercepter-basic-auth.service.ts file
import { HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BasicAuthenticationService } from '../basic-authentication.service';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpIntercepterBasicAuthService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(
    private basicAuthenticationService: BasicAuthenticationService
  ) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    
    let basicAuthHeaderString = this.basicAuthenticationService.getAuthenticatedToken();
    let username = this.basicAuthenticationService.getAuthenticatedUser();

    if (basicAuthHeaderString && username) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: basicAuthHeaderString
        }
      })
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}


Why not post your angular client code that is sending the request to your spring boot backend?
But, in the absence of that use postman to send request to your backend, and please remember to supply basic authentication before sending your request to the backend

I provide my github link, kindly clone it and try to recheck . In backend part it work fine . But from frontend it shows the cors error.

Well , I wanted to, but the link seems to have some certificate issued that's why am not opening the link

Issue Resolved. Thank you. Made a silly mistake. Resolved.
